# recursion difference between --n , and n-1 in recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

I need someone to tell me the difference between these two codes :

```
public static int test(int n)
{
    if(n>2){
        int sum =0;
        int x=n;
        if(n%3!=0)
        sum+=test(x-1);
        System.out.println(n+" ");
        sum+=test(x-1)+test(x-2);
        return sum;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n+" ");
        return n+1 ; 
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(test(5));
    }

}
```

and :

```
public static int test(int n)
{
    if(n>2){
        int sum =0;
        int x=n;
        if(n%3!=0)
        sum+=test(--x);
        System.out.println(n+" ");
        sum+=test(x-1)+test(x-2);
        return sum;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(n+" ");
        return n+1 ; 
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(test(5));
    }

}
```

To be more precise, I am curious about the following line 
`sum+=test(--x); vs sum+=test(x-1);`  it gives a different output, can you tell me how does a recusrion behave when we have recursion(--x)
**edit :**
for sum+=test(x-1) it gives the following :
3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 5 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 31 and i get this part,
but for sum+=test(--x) the output is :
3 2 1 4 2 1 5 3 2 1 2 18

Comment: What do you think `--x` and `x-1` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: In a situation like this your first attempt at solving the issue should be by stepping through the code either using a debugger, print statements or just writing it down by hand. Then you'll find out for yourself what differs.

Comment: A good approach to this would be to start by googling for the operators. Which would quite likely lead to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that `x` is used after the line in question. `--x` gives you the same value as `x - 1`, but it also modifies the value of `x` to be `x - 1`. Because of that, it will change the behavior of the code after that line.

Answer (score 3):

If `x`'s value is `10`, this line `sum+=test(x-1)+test(x-2)` will give :

- `sum+=test(9)+test(8);` for the first example.
- `sum+=test(8)+test(7);` for the second.

### Why?

Because in the second example, calling `--x` will change the value of `x` by decrementing it. In the first example, its value doesn't change since we're passing the result of an arithmetic operation as parameter (`x-1`)

Comment: Furthermore, the "pre-decrement" operator (--x is a pre-decrement of x) operates on x before x is used in the statement where the expression appears. This is a holdover from when (a) C was being used to write an operating system on machines so slow that it was often worthwhile to save every possible machine cycle, (b) it was being compiled specifically for machines that had an addressing mode that allowed an instruction to access memory and increment or decrement the index into that memory in the same machine instruction.

Comment: @arcy Indeed but as it did not made part of the differences between both codes, I did not mention that.

Answer (score 0):

After you use ++x, x value is changed

```
sum+=test(--x); //after this x=x-1

sum+=test(x-1); //after this x is still x
```

Comment: thanks, i did not know that this logic works inside of a recursive call also

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `--x` and `x-1` in a *recursive call* compared to one that is not recursive. In fact, when it comes to recursive calls there are very little difference from normal calls. An example:

```
public static int test1(int n)
{
  System.out.println(n+1); 
  return n;
}

public static int test2(int n)
{
  System.out.println(n++); 
  return n;
}

public static int test3(int n)
{
  System.out.println(++n); 
  return n;
}
```

Here i'm calling `System.out.println` but it really doesn't matter. I could have recursed and from the callee point of view it works the same. The expression for the arguments are evaluated in this function and then the call is made with the values they amount to and when it's finished the function continues until either the end or a return statement.

So if I'm calling these 3 functions with `1` as argument these are the results:

```
function  prints  returns because
test1     2       1       n is never changed in this function
test2     1       2       n is incremented but the result is the value before the action
test3     2       2       n is incremented and since its ++n the new value is the result of the expression
```

Dennis Richie  was involved in both B and C and it's in these languages most of the crazy syntax like `--n` comes from.

When it comes to functions it's perhaps not wise to mutate it's arguments. It makes clearer code, especially in recursive functions. Thus `test1` would be the best but if you wanted the `test3` version making a variable would make the code more readable:

```
public static int test3(int n)
{
  int value = n + 1;
  System.out.println(value); 
  return value;
}
```

Now that's easier to read, isn't it?